# Creating Padding/Margin with Bullet Points

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to figure out how to move my bullet points over with a margin/padding.  No matter what I do, it moves over the words and not the bullet points within the DIV.  Any help is appreciated and I made a JSFiddle to show sort of what I have.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z8Me4/

```
.lymelist li {
background: url(images/columnbullet.png) no-repeat left 4px;
font: normal 12px/18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #4f4f4f;
padding-left: 23px;
margin: 5px 0;
}
.lymelist li ul li {
background: none;
list-style: lower-alpha;
padding-left: 0;
margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: in what browser you check it? because i can't see the problem

Comment: always run your html through a validator! http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `list-style-position:inside;`
http://jsfiddle.net/Z8Me4/1/

you also have your paragraph tag inside your ul tag, that won't work, take a look...
http://jsfiddle.net/Z8Me4/4/

```
<ul class="one_column lymelist">
  <p>Some 2013 Highlights:</p>
  <p><B><u>Public Health and Epidemiology</u></B></p>
  <li>CDC revises of number of new Lyme cases to 300,000 a year</li>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

needs to change to:

```
<p>Some 2013 Highlights:</p>

<p><B><u>Public Health and Epidemiology</u></B></p>

<ul class="one_column lymelist">
  <li>CDC revises of number of new Lyme cases to 300,000 a year</li>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

then you will be able to indent the `li` tag or the `ul` tag however you want.

Comment: So in the JSFiddle it worked, but not on my actual webpage when I changed the CSS.  If you wouldn't mind looking, here is the webpage; you can see in the CSS I added the list-style-position: inside tag.

http://www.lymemd.org/indexmm4.php

I'm also unsure what you mean when you say that it won't work.  Could you explain?  Thank you!

Comment: sure, the `ul` tag is only allowed to have `li` tags inside of it. you have `p` tags. i have explained this better in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot move the bullets. You need to move the li content. Wrap your li content inside the **span** and give relative position to it

```
<ul>
     <li><span>CDC revises of number of new Lyme cases to 300,000 a year</span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
li span

    {
        position:relative;
        left:-5px;
    }
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cnWK7/